# Is there a constructor in this piece of code?

Tags: java, constructor

Is there a constructor in this piece of code? Which part in this code is the constructor?

```
class Bicycle {
    int cadance = 0;
    int speed = 0;
    int gear = 0;

    void changeCadance(int changeCadence) {
        cadance = changeCadence;
    }

    void changeGear(int changeGear) {
        gear = changeGear;
    }

    void changeSpeed(int changeSpeed) {
        speed = changeSpeed;
    }

    void printState() {
        System.out.print("Cadance = "+cadance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there is an implied default constructor.  It is never spelled out, but it is understood to be there by the IDE and compiler.  Non static classes are generally understood to have a constructor, and thus if no constructor is created explicitly, the **default constructor** is used.  It takes no arguments, and does not really do anything but initialize the class with the explicitly provided property values.  Sometimes, you can get away with just the default.

For a little more information, I am linking the Wikipedia article for [Default Constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_constructor) as I think it does a pretty good job of explaining it across several languages.

Essentially it says that the default constructor is supplied by the compiler (and the IDE will normally allow you to call it also) if a parameterless constructor is not explicitly given in the class.  So if I write a constructor that takes and parameter, but I don't write a constructor that takes no arguments, the compiler will STILL supply one.

This is a bit of a generalization as some languages differ a bit, but I think that most doe the above.

Comment: what is a default constructor. is it predefined in java library ?

Comment: Really it is just based on convention.  The compiler knows that if one is not supplied, then it creates one that does nothing but instance and initialize the class.  Compilers actually do a lot of this.  In some languages you can write inline property declarations like 'public bool IsActive {get;set;}' which the compiler will expand to the full property block complete with a private backing field and whatnot.  Convention is a powerful tool where there is an implied rule that everyone uses, and the compiler understands it is supposed to do something when that rule is used.

Comment: Thanks that helped me visualize constructors.

Comment: Great!  Be sure to mark it as answer if it resolved your problem.  Mark it with an upvote (if you have not done so) if it increased you knowledge on an issue.  This helps others down the line identify answers to their problems more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is an *implied default constructor*.

It is the convention in Java (and other languages) to provide an empty constructor (with no parameters) if no other constructors have been defined.

It is worthy to note that as soon as you add any constructors with parameters then the implied default constructor is not available anymore.